# scrolltop within a div

Tags: javascript, html, scrolltop

I have created a scrollable div and have tried to make use of scrolltop to only scroll within said div container.

How ever it scrolls the whole body and I have being unable to make any progress to get it to work the way I want.

My best guess is that it may have something to do with the following script

```
y1 = document.getElementById('sheet').scrollTop;
y2 = y1 + window.innerHeight;
yb = parseInt((y + h) * scale) + y_offset + scrollMargin;
yt = parseInt(y * scale) + y_offset - scrollMargin;
if(yt < y1){
 scrollTo(0,yt)
}
if(yb > y2){
 scrollTo(0, yb - window.innerHeight)
}
```

The following is a link to an example of the problem I am trying to solve.
http://3djakedesigns.org/example/Ghiribizzi%20No%201a.html

As you see it moves the whole body, instead of just scrolling within the div container.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop)

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle may help you till somepoint

http://jsfiddle.net/Ezge8/94/

```
$('#scrollBtn').click(function(){
    $('.sss').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".test1").offset().top
}, 100);
});
```